# Checking the convergence of a requested series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the series $\sum \frac{1 + (-1)^{n+1} (2n+1)}{4}$ converge$?$

I partitioned the series in two parts, when n is even $\sum -\frac{n}{2}$ and when $n$ is odd, $\sum \frac{n+1}{2}$

Both series are divergent, so this doesn't conclude anything.

$N^\text{th}$ terms of these series are not zero. Can I say from here that the series is divergent or there's another way to check the convergence of such series?

Comment: I assumed you didn't want to check the "convenience" of a series, so I fixed your title accordingly. Since the system didn't allow me to change just that one word, I added the "requested" adjective.

Answer (score 2):

The last thing you said is correct :
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n \neq 0 \; \Rightarrow \; \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \textrm{ diverges.}$$

Answer (score 2):

Apply the divergence test.

$$\sum \frac{1 + (-1)^{n+1} (2n+1)}{4}$$ diverges since $$\frac{1 + (-1)^{n+1} (2n+1)}{4}$$ does not tend to zero as $n$ goes to $\infty$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Compute the partial sums. Note that $a_n + a_{n+1}=0$ when $n$ is odd.